# DB Structure - Storage of relationships

Tags: mysql, rdbms

This is a complex problem, so I'm going to try to simplify it.

I have a mysql instance on my server hosting a number of schemas for different purposes.  The schemas are structured generally (not perfectly) in a [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) fashion.  I need to transition information into and out of that structure on a regular basis.

**Example1**: in order to present the information on a webpage, I get the information, stick it into a complex object, which I then pass via json to the webpage, where I convert the json into a complex javascript object, which I then present with [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/) and similar things.

**Conclusion**: This resulted in a *lot* of logic being put into multiple places so that I could associate the values on the page with the values in the database.

**Example2**: in order to allow users to import information from a pdf, I have a lot of information stored in pdf form fields.  In this case, I didn't write the pdf though, so the form fields aren't named in such a way that all of this logic is easy enough to write 3 or more times for [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete).

**Conclusion**: This resulted in my copying a list of the pdf form fields to a table in the database, so that I could then somehow associate them with where their data should be placed.  The problem that arose is that the fields on the pdf would need to associate with schema.table.column and the only way I found to store that information was via a [VARCHAR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html)

Neither of the examples are referring to a small amount of data (something like 6 tables in example 1 and somewhere around 1400 pdf form fields in example 2).  Given *Example1* and the resulting logic being stored multiple places, it seemed logical to build *Example2*, where I could store the **relationships** between data in the database where they could be accessed and changed consistently and for all involved methods.

Now, it's quite possible I'm just being stupid and all of my googling hasn't come across that there's an easy way to associate this data with the correct schema.table.column  If this is the case, then telling me the right way to do that is the simple answer here.

However, and this is where I get confused.  I have always been told that you never want to store information about a database in the database, especially not as strings (varchar).  This seems wrong on so many levels and I just can't figure out if I'm being stupid, and it's better to follow *Example1* or if there's some trick here that I've missed about database structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where you got *"... never ... store information about a database in the database"*.  With an EAV model it is normal to store the metamodel (the entity types and their allowable attributes) in the database itself so that it is self-describing.  If you had to change the metamodel, would you rather change code or a few rows in a table?

The main drawback to EAV databases is that you lose the ability to do simple joins.  Join-type operations become much more complex.  Like everything else in life, you make tradeoffs depending on your requirements.  I have seen self-describing EAV architectures used very successfully.

Comment: is there a better structure to use than EAV for a situation like this?

Comment: If you need to cope with a constantly changing metamodel, i.e. if you'd constantly be changing the DB schema (adding/removing/changing tables and column definitions) then an EAV architecture is exactly what you need.  If schema changes are very few and very far between, then a traditional normalized architecture will work.

Comment: neither seems to eliminate the need to store schema.table.column in the database in order to associate the data with it's likely location.  Based on you're answer, I'm guessing you're saying that I don't need to eliminate that need?

Comment: That's correct.  A typical EAV will have a table defining the "Object" types, giving each one a distinct ID, a table defining each type's attributes (FK to the "object type" table).  There will be instance tables for the object instances and attribute instances, with FKs back to the type tables.  You will have to think about the problem (and provide code) at two distinct levels: maintenance of the instance data, and maintenance of the metamodel.